# AngularJS/Ionic - NG Selected based on item value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

**Solved**

I'm using a form control group, so one must set the default value via that, like so:

```
this.data.get('selectedSite').setValue(oldActive)
```

Hope this helps someone!

---

I'm binding an array to an ion-select component with the following code:

```
<ion-select formControlName="selectedSite" >
    <ion-option color="light" *ngFor="let site of sites" value="{{site.site}}" ng-selected="site.active == '1'">{{site.site}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Where the the site has a 1, for active, the site should be selected by default. Then array is constructed like so:

```
this.sql.query('SELECT site,active FROM Site_tbl ORDER BY site ASC').then((res) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < res.res.rows.length; i++) {
        this.sites.push({ site: res.res.rows.item(i).site, active: res.res.rows.item(i).active })
    }
})
```

And the resultant array looks like this:

```
Array[44]
   0: Object
       active: 0
       site: "Site 1"
   1: Object
       active: 1
       site: "Site 2"
   2: Object
       active: 0
       site: "Site 3"
   ....
```

So in this case, Site 2 should be selected. The list of sites is bound to the list succesfully, I can see their names in the list (the ngFor repeat works in that regard) but the ng-selected condition seems to have no effect, the box select box shows as empty by default, rather than showing the selected (active) site.

Basic problem, but I've tried everything I can think of, help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the double curly braces in your `ng-selected` expression. It should read:

```
<ion-select formControlName="selectedSite" >
    <ion-option color="light" *ngFor="let site of sites" 
     value="{{site.site}}" ng-selected="{{site.active}}">{{site.site}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, it returns the following error: `Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-selected' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-option'.`- taking the curly braces out stops the error, but doesn't set the default value.

Comment: Try replacing "ng-selected" with "selected", which should be recognized by ion-option.

Comment: `<ion-option *ngFor="let site of sites" selected="{{site.active}}" value="{{site.active}}">{{site.site}}</ion-option>` - has no effect :(

Comment: I fixed it, issue was with a formGroup (see my edit) - thanks for the help though! :D